# VFP Entity Framework Provider getting encrypted password as empty string

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foxpro, visual-foxpro

I am using VFP Entity Framework Provider for .NET (EF) to read data from a VFP database.
In the user table there is a password column. When I get focus in the password cell in VFP I can easily copy the value and edit it:

[image: Normal password field]

On the .NET side the value is read without any problems.

Now once in a while there is a peculiar row with a password with trailing spaces:

[image: Password with trailing spaces without]

When I put focus in that cell VFP acts like there's no value at all:

[image: Password with trailing spaces cell with focus]

When I retrieve that user in my program using Entity Framework I get an empty string. I don't know how this password is generated, all I know is that it works for the original VFP program using the database. There is no problem with other passwords, and this happens rather rarely, but repetitively.

What is the source of that behavior? Is there a workaround to retrieve the correct value on the .NET or VFP side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted Tom Brothers, the creator of VFP provider for EF simultaneously to posting this question. He took his time and actually came up with the following diagnosis:

> The problem is that the invalid password’s first character is actually a null (ascii 0).  Typically, a null character is used as a string terminator.  Given this scenario .Net is returning an empty string because it didn’t find any characters before the null.  You can verify things are working the way I described them by inserting a null in the middle of one of your working passwords to see that it (“it” being .Net or the browse window) doesn’t return any characters after the null.  **But the real annoying thing in your case is that VFP doesn’t seem to use the null as a terminator when accessing the table field directly… which is inconsistent with how the browse windows works when you click on the cell to edit the value**.

This is not a solution for the problem but constitutes the most completed answer. Thank you Tom!

Answer (score 1):

I'd Base64-encode the encrypted password before storing, and reverse that before using it. Therefore it will only be stored using printable characters.

Comment: I get to only read the database, I can't touch the code of the actual solution

Comment: In that case I would think your options are to see what's going wrong in the Visual FoxPro EF provider source, or get in touch with Tom Brothers (author of same) and see if he has any ideas.

Comment: Oh, and smack the original author in the head for not storing encrypted passwords properly.

Comment: Oh, I'd love to, but I think this piece might be old enough to assume he's retired...

Answer (score 0):

I would probably go along with Alan regarding storing it in base-64 due to the non-printable characters that LOOK like spaces but are not...  VFP has a "cryptor" class and that MIGHT be what the strings are stored from.  Now, if the existing VFP app is still using those passwords, you obviously do not want to break that application level access vs your E/F C# solution.